# XamForms.Controls.Calendar Special Dates Text Blurry

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using XamForms.Controls.Calendar in my Xamarin.Forms project everything works great, but the texts entered in the "Text" section of the SpeacialDates property appear blurred on the iOS platform, how can I solve it?

DrawText feature ios also have the same way, despite the intense research of this feature could not solve the blur problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTtMU.jpg "Screenshot"

```
   protected void DrawText(CGContext g, Pattern p, CGRect r)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Text)) return;//Copperplate-Light" KohinoorTelugu-Light
        string fontname = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet ? "KohinoorTelugu-Light" : "GillSans-UltraBold";//GillSans-UltraBold
        var bounds = p.Text.StringSize(UIFont.FromName(fontname, p.TextSize));
        //"GillSans-UltraBold
        var al = (int)p.TextAlign;
        var x = r.X;
        if ((al & 2) == 2) // center
        {
            x = r.X + (int)Math.Round(r.Width / 2.0) - (int)Math.Round(bounds.Width / 2.0);
        }
        else if ((al & 4) == 4) // right
        {
            x = (r.X + r.Width) - bounds.Width - 2;
        }
        var y = r.Y + (int)Math.Round(bounds.Height / 2.0) + 2;
        if ((al & 16) == 16) // middle
        {
            y = r.Y + (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Height / 2.0) + (int)Math.Round(bounds.Height / 5.0);
        }
        else if ((al & 32) == 32) // bottom
        {
            y = (r.Y + r.Height) - 2;
        }
        g.SaveState();

        g.SetShouldAntialias(true);
        g.SetShouldSmoothFonts(true);
        g.SetAllowsFontSmoothing(true);
        g.SetAllowsAntialiasing(true);
        g.SetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts(false);
        g.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.High;
        g.SetAllowsSubpixelPositioning(false);
        g.SetAllowsFontSubpixelQuantization(false);
        g.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.High;


        g.TranslateCTM(0, Bounds.Height);
        g.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
        g.SetStrokeColor(p.TextColor.ToCGColor());
        g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.EOFillStroke);
        g.SetFillColor(p.TextColor.ToCGColor());
        g.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.FillStrokeClip);
        g.SelectFont(fontname, p.TextSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        g.ShowTextAtPoint(x, Bounds.Height - y, p.Text);
        g.RestoreState();
    }
}
```

Comment: It could better to open an issue at the  XamForms.Controls.Calendar GitHub.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I already did this.

https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/issues